# How to make download functionality compatible with mobile browsers using React?

Tags: reactjs, express, download, cross-browser, mern

My download link functionality works on desktop browsers and the mobile version of chrome but doesn't work on mobile browsers like ucbrowser and opera mini. I am running the code locally.

I'm serving a zip file with express,this works fine:

```
app.get('/download/:id', (req, res) => {
const file = req.params.id;
 res.download(path.join(__dirname,"downloadable", file+".zip"),function(err)
 {
  if(err) console.log(err);
   console.log("downloaded")
}); 
});
```

In the frontend I have tried all of these functions, they all have the same behavior:

```
const tryDownloadOne = (url, filename) => {  //using js-file-download library
  axios.get(url, {
    responseType: 'blob',
  })
  .then((res) => {
    fileDownload(res.data, filename)
  })
}

const tryDownloadTwo = async(url,fileName)=>{        //creating dummy anchor tag
 const response = await axios.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' });
if (response.data.error) console.error(response.data.error)
const fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
const fileLink = document.createElement('a');
fileLink.href = fileURL;
console.log(response.headers["content-disposition"]);
fileLink.setAttribute('download', fileName);
document.body.appendChild(fileLink);
fileLink.click();
fileLink.remove();
}

const tryDownloadThree=async(url,fileName)=>{  //using file saver library
const res=await fetch(url);
 const blob=await res.blob();
saveAs(blob, fileName);
}
```

The html part looks like this

```
 <button className="submit" onClick={()=>tryDownloadOne("/download/"+downloadFolder,currentFolder+".zip")} >download</button>
```